# Identifying flying insect from northern Poland / Baltic Sea area

Tags: entomology, species-identification, taxonomy

Found during this year vacations at Baltic Sea ([northern parts of Poland](https://www.google.pl/maps/place/O%C5%9Brodek+Wypoczynkowy+Z%C5%82ota+Pla%C5%BCa/@54.3123769,16.2070634,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x57e6359b8cca0ff3)):

[image]

I don't have a picture containing other object, for size verification, but I'd say, that it was 3-4 cm long.

There were two interesting characteristics of this insect, that I haven't found in case of any other:

- it was not flying / running away, when when being chased / waived by a hand; you actually had to snap it with a finger and sent it airborn, to make it fly away,
- once touched by finger or upon falling from certain height it was pretending dead, but when you tried to remove "dead body" it turned out in most cases that it is alive and it was flying over.

This is all I can tell about this insect. Can someone help me with identifying, what species is it?

Comment: A weevil perhaps? Somewhere to start!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possibly a [vine weevil (*Otiorhynchus sulcatus*)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otiorhynchus_sulcatus)

[image]

Others of the family:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a good guess, however [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otiorhynchus_sulcatus#Overview): "_The adult weevil is matte black with fused wing covers, and **is unable to fly**_" is making me a little bit susspicious, because I'm pretty sure, that insects observed by me were able to fly. Or maybe they were just jumping quite high? I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, notice the absence of the stripe on the [pronoto](http://www.antoniomachado.net/galleries/illustration/anatomy-of-a-weevil/) in your guess that is very clear in the OP's specimen. I think you're right that it is likely a weevil of some sort, but you do not have the correct species.